# Conditional Expectation with discrete Poisson Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$, $Y$ be two discrete Poisson Random Variables such that $X \sim \mathcal P(\lambda)$ and $X \sim \mathcal P(\mu)$.

We are asked to evaluate $\mathbb E (X^2+Y^2|X+Y=n)$

We know the sum of $X$ and $Y$ :
$$X+Y \sim \mathcal P(\lambda+\mu)$$
I tried using this methode :

$X^2 + Y^2 = (X+Y)^2 - 2XY$

We get by replacing in the expectation and by the linearity of the expectation :

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb E (X^2+Y^2|X+Y=n) 
&= \mathbb E ((X+Y)^2-2XY|X+Y=n)\\
&= \mathbb E ((X+Y)^2|X+Y=n)-2\mathbb E(XY|X+Y=n)\\
&= \mathbb E (n^2|X+Y=n)-2\mathbb E(XY|X+Y=n) \hspace{1cm} \text{since }X+Y=n \\
&= n^2 -2\mathbb E(XY|X+Y=n)
\end{align*}
$$
And here I got stuck calculating the term $\mathbb E(XY|X+Y=n)$

Also this idea
$$\mathbb E (X^2+Y^2|X+Y=n)=\mathbb E (X^2|X+Y=n) +\mathbb E (Y^2|X+Y=n)$$
didn't work quite well. Maybe I still have some problems understanding the concept.

Thank you !

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent Poisson, then $X$ (or $Y$) conditioned on $X+Y$ has a standard distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you know about Poisson distributions.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the conditional distribution for $X$ given $X+Y=n$ is $\mathrm{Bin}(n, \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu})$, and similarly for $Y$ is $\mathrm{Bin}(n, \frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu})$

So $\mathbb E[X \mid X+Y=n]=n\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$, $\mathrm{Var}(X \mid X+Y=n)= n\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+mu}(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu})$ and  $\mathbb E[X^2 \mid X+Y=n]=n\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu} +(n^2-n)\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^2 $ and similarly  $E[Y^2 \mid X+Y=n]=n\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu} +(n^2-n)\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^2$

Thus $E[X^2 +Y^2\mid X+Y=n] = n +(n^2-n)\frac{\lambda^2+\mu^2}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}= n^2 -\frac{2\lambda\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2} n(n-1) $

Comment: I understood your answer, and it's cleat. But how about the first method ? It doesn't work ?

Comment: @Hamdiken  I do not see an easy way to find $\mathbb E[XY \mid X+Y=n] = \frac{\lambda\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2} n(n-1)$ - if that is what it is - except by first finding $\mathbb E[X^2 \mid X+Y=n] $